# Font size too large while retrieving the screen from history

Tags: blackberry

When I retrieve the screen from history, I get the font size of the text as so large,
I use VFM within screen and i use custom component within it, which uses Graphics class to draw text.

When i press back button, it switches to history page, which shows up, with bigFont as well as some images from the previous page also shows up.

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean to say that when you press back button of blackberry device then the screen that was present below the current screen in the stack appears some what distorted.

Usually it(below screen) appears the same as it was before any other screen was pushed over it.

Did u tried calling invalidate method in the onExposed method of the distorted screen.

May be it helps!!!!